# How to select multiple values inside array of JSON values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple arrays of JSON values:

```
[{"header": "A", "value": "test"}, {"header": "B", "value": "test1"}, {"header": "C", "value": "test2"}]

[{"header": "A1", "value": "test"}, {"header": "B1", "value": "test1"}, {"header": "C1", "value": "test2"}]

[{"header": "A2", "value": "test"}, {"header": "B2", "value": "test1"}, {"header": "C2", "value": "test2"}]
```

How do I select all of the headers in the array of JSONs?
I used JSON_VALUE and can only get the provided array index:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(Columns, '$[0].header') FROM Files
```

```
1: A
2: A1
3: A2
```

My expected result is:

```
1: A, B, C
2: A1, B1, C1
3: A2, B2, C2
```

Comment: Please add the DBMS i guess it is Mongo ?

Comment: I'm using SQL in ssms @jmvcollaborator

Comment: MS Sql, please edit your answer to add Tags related to the tech stack.

Comment: `select h.headers
from Files as f
cross apply (select string_agg(json_value(o.value, '$.header'), ',') within group(order by cast(o.[key] as int)) as headers
 from openjson(f.Columns) as o) as h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like:

```
SELECT 
  JSON_VALUE(Columns, '$[0].header') as Col1, 
  JSON_VALUE(Columns, '$[1].header') as Col2,
  JSON_VALUE(Columns, '$[2].header') as Col3 FROM Files;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/irBPHjIT)

EDIT: If key, header would do:

SELECT t.[key], z.header
from files
cross apply OpenJson(Columns) t
cross apply OpenJson(t.Value) with (header VARCHAR(10)) z;

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/04NqeyoT)

With string_agg added:

```
SELECT t.[key], string_agg(z.header,',') headers
  from files 
  cross apply OpenJson(Columns) t
  cross apply OpenJson(t.Value) with (header VARCHAR(10)) z
group by t.[key];
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/C149TBoT)

Comment: I need to make it dynamic because I may add more or delete the json fields so I can't just hard code the indexes in. I tried 
SELECT 
  JSON_VALUE(Columns, '$[*].header') as Col1 FROM Files; 
but it didn't work

Comment: @Oinkvietnam, then maybe you could use it in key, header style and then use string_agg() to get by grouping on key. See the edit for key, header.